# ¿Qué significa "lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás"?

Tags: expresiones, significado-en-contexto

Un conocido comentó lo siguiente:

> Yo vivi en esa ciudad. Yo para ser sincero no me gustó. La gente no es amable. Lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás.

¿Qué significa "lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás" en este contexto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un refrán (que personalmente no conocía `La ley del embudo, para mí lo ancho y para ti lo agudo`) pero que grafica bien un sentido de no proporción e inequidad en el trato y la búsqueda del interés propio.

El hablante acude a esa metáfora para aludir a la no amabilidad (falta de solidaridad) encontrada en su experiencia en una ciudad.  Transmite así una insatisfacción como resumen crítico de un tono general  de desconsideración campante;  es la queja al norte de sobrevivencia personal en el trato humano, de la prevalencia del provecho individual, a expensas de otros.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Comment: No sé si me podrían explicar el significado de "lo ancho" y el de "lo estrecho" en ese caso. Muchas gracias otra vez 

Answer (score 4):

Se trata de la conocida como [“ley del embudo”](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_del_embudo), por la cual las normas se aplican de forma diferente a unos u otros.

Comment: Heads I win, tails you lose.