# El significado de "ancho" y "estrecho" en "lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás"

Tags: significado-en-contexto

Entiendo que "lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás" es la ley del embudo, que es "una expresión acuñada popularmente para denunciar una injusticia evidente que nadie se atreve a subvertir y que a menudo surge de alguna confrontación o disputa en la que vence siempre el más fuerte, no el que tiene más razón, "atentando" contra la equidad."

Pero, ¿me podrían explicar el significado de "ancho" y el de "estrecho" en "lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás"? Muchas gracias

Comment: Entiendo que ya has visto la pregunta anterior [¿Qué significa “lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/36903/5481). Un embudo tiene tanto un lado ancho como uno estrecho. Cuando tú intentas pasar por un sitio, es más fácil hacerlo por un sitio ancho que por uno estrecho. Así que esa ley del embudo quiere decir "para mi facilidades (pasar por un sitio ancho) y para los demás restricciones (algo estrecho). La "ley del embudo" también se llama "del doble rasero" (medir con distinta vara). Ancho = facilidades. Estrecho = dificultades.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por su respuesta!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [¿Qué significa "lo ancho para mí, lo estrecho para los demás"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/36903/qu%c3%a9-significa-lo-ancho-para-m%c3%ad-lo-estrecho-para-los-dem%c3%a1s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparte de usar 'ancho' y 'estrecho' como metáfora de los dos extremos de un embudo, dado que la expresión resalta una posición egoísta: "Lo mejor/bueno para mí y el resto/lo peor/lo malo para los demás", en este caso se usa "ancho" como algo mejor que "estrecho".
Es decir, si tú le preguntas a alguien que elija entre dos objetos iguales pero uno más grande que otro, habitualmente asumimos que algo más grande siempre es "mejor" que algo más pequeño. Dado que algo "ancho" es algo también más grande que algo estrecho, se usa "ancho" como sinónimo de "mejor/bueno" y estrecho como sinónimo de "peor/malo".

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias a sus explicaciones !